# Is admob ID is necessary while testing on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob, logcat, ads

I cant able to fetch my ads on emulator getting the error in logcat as follows:

```
Invalid unlnown request error: cannot determine request type Is your add unit id correct.
OnFailedToReceiveAd( Invalid ad Request);
```

In my xml file I got this error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

even after putting my **original admob ID** it shows the same error.

Comment: Show your Adview config. What AdUnitId are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its necessary.
I would suggest you to use latest google play services. The one you are using is going to be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary but you can still work with this **dummy id for admob banner**

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

and **dummy id for admob Interstitial**

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

To avoid getting in troubles with Admob if you clicked the ad accidentally

And **remember to replace** those dummy ids by your real ones before publishing your app